# Can't use yum on guest - suspect port 80 forwarding in iptables on host at fault?

Tags: centos, iptables, kvm-virtualization, yum

What's wrong with this set-up?  Both host and guest are CentOS 6.5

Specifically, I can't run yum on the guest.

I can ping happily to/from the guest, including pinging mirrorlist.centos.org

**If I remove the port 80 rule from the host iptables (see below) then yum works fine.  But I need that rule in place so I can use the guest as a publicly-accessible webserver.**

yum update output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Guest has an IP of 192.168.122.47, and the ssh port forwarding I have set up below works, but yum does not.

Guest iptables has been disabled.

Host iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:560]
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:316]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4:316]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:560]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:560]
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 792 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.47:22
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.47:80
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May 10 15:54:24 2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-NATting; you are NATting not just *in*bound connections to port 80, but *out*bound ones as well.  Modify the NAT rule to specify that the traffic must be coming in from outside, eg

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.47:80
```

and it will stop matching (and interfering with) legitimate outbound traffic to external webservers.

Comment: Thank you, I'm yet to really get my head around iptables - need to spend some time reading up and playing around rather than just copying and pasting from google...